# Mongo query existence and value of embedded object property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

A 5,000 to 10,000 record Mongo collection contains:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e16c34c78b04f43f2f55a0"), 
    "appID" : NumberInt(4830800), 
    "topics" : {
        "test1" : 1.440899998865E12, 
        "test2" : 1.440899998865E12, 
        "test3" : 1.440899998865E12, 
        "test4" : 1.440899998865E12
    }, 
}
```

I need to query for records that contain a specified property name in the topics field and where the value of the specified name is greater than or equal to a given number.

something like

```
find({"topics.test1": { $gte: 1440825382535 }})
```

This query works as expected, returning a set of records that have a test1 property with a test1 value >= 1440825382535

If I create a simple index on the topics field `explain()` says that no index is used for the query (understandably).

The set of property names that may be searched for *is not predefined*.  The query is dynamically built based on names that are found elsewhere.

Is there a way to index this table to speed up queries?  The full scan query takes quite a bit of time to run (on the order of 1.5 seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this type of data indexable, you need to change the schema to make `topics` an array and move the dynamic `test1`, `test2`, etc. keys into values.

So something like:

```javascript
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e16c34c78b04f43f2f55a0"), 
    "appID" : NumberInt(4830800), 
    "topics" : [
        {name: "test1", value: 1.440899998865E12}, 
        {name: "test2", value: 1.440899998865E12}, 
        {name: "test3", value: 1.440899998865E12}, 
        {name: "test4", value: 1.440899998865E12}
    ] 
}
```

Then your query changes to:

```javascript
find({topics: {$elemMatch: {name: 'test1', value: {$gte: 1440825382535}}}})
```

Which you can support with an index of:

```javascript
{'topics.name': 1, 'topics.value': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Was a little confused at what you were trying to do, but maybe something like this?

```
find({"topics.test1": {$exists: true}, { $gte: 1440825382535 }})
```